# MySQL: select row only where closest to date has column value

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, in-subquery

I want to return all rows that were public in May (2019-05), so if a row was turned to draft (and not back to public) at any point before the end of May, I don't want it. For example:

```
id | post_id | status | date
-------------------------
 1 | 1       | draft  | 2019-03-25
 2 | 1       | public | 2019-04-02
 3 | 1       | draft  | 2019-05-25
 4 | 2       | draft  | 2019-03-10
 5 | 2       | public | 2019-04-01
 6 | 2       | draft  | 2019-06-01
```

The desired result for the above would return `post_id 2` because its last status change prior to the end of May was to `public`.

`post_id 1` was put back in draft before the end of May, so it would not be included.

I'm not sure how to use the correct join or sub-queries to do this as efficiently as possible.

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work as you expected?

Comment: Hint: write a query that finds all the draft posts, then use NOT IN to exclude them.

Comment: I think using a `CASE` expression would work really well to get your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the status as of 2019-05-31.  A correlated subquery seems like the simplest solution:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.post_id = t.post_id and
                      t2.date <= '2019-05-31'
               );
```

To get the ones that are public, just add a `WHERE` condition:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.post_id = t.post_id and
                      t2.date <= '2019-05-31'
               ) and
      t.status = 'public';
```

For performance, you want an index on `(post_id, date)`.

You can also phrase this using a `JOIN`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t2.post_id, max(t2.date) as max_date
      from t t2
      where t2.date <= '2019-05-31'
      group by t2.post_id
     ) t2
     on t2.max_date = t.date
where t.status = 'public';
```

I would expect the correlated subquery to have better performance with the right indexes.  However, sometimes MySQL surprises me.

Answer (score 0):

we need to determine whether

1. the status of each `post_id` is `public` prior to the month `May` (the subquery with max(date)),
2. any `post_id` exists with status not equals `public` within the month `May`,
3. and then exclude the `post_id` satisfying the matter 2.

So, you can use :

```
select distinct t1.post_id
  from tab t1
where t1.post_id not in
    (
     select distinct t1.post_id
       from tab t1
       join
       (
        select post_id, max(date) as date
          from tab 
         where '2019-05-01'> date
         group by post_id ) t2
         on t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
      where t1.status != 'public' 
        and t1.date < '2019-06-01' 
        and t1.date > '2019-04-30'
);

+---------+
| POST_ID |
+---------+
|    2    |
+---------+
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d9f46160e6fe2071791ac9aed9396ec4)</kbd>